# dont drag window header outside of browser in extjs

Tags: forms, extjs

I have create a form in extjs, when i drag it, the portion of draggable area goes outside of browser and I have no oprtion but only refresg the page again. Is there any function so that i can restrict the draggable area, so the user cant drag the window outside of browser.

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer for my question.

Comment: can you post your answer here so everyone can use it if they get same problem

Comment: you need to add 

constrain: true, 

In .js file where your window gets created.

Answer (score 11):

You can set `constrain: true` in the `Ext.Window` config